# What is the proper way to create Cancel Button that closes dialog in GTK+?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3

The question is for GTK+ programing in C++.
I have a main window with a button that activates a dialog window. The dialog window has OK and CANCEL buttons. I did it that way so when I hit the cancel button the dialog is closed. But once it is closed I cannot call it again with the button in the main window.

I have tried to call the dialog `delete-event` on the button click. I also tried to call the dialog `destroy event` when the button is clicked. But in both cases the dialog is destroyed and it does not show when I click the button that calls the dialog.

Comment: please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this is a follow up of your other question on the topic:
[How to properly close a dialog made in Glade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46519999/how-to-properly-close-a-dialog-made-in-glade)

If it was created using `GtkBuilder`, if you destroy the window, it's really destroyed: `GtkBuilder` has created the widgets at parsing time, not when you call `get_object`, and won't create them again. So I think you should just hide the dialog with something like `gtk_widget_hide_on_delete`, and show it again when you click on the button in your main dialog.

Comment: I was thinking about that too but i was not sure if he used GtkBuilder. GtkBuilder instantiates at load. Once destroyed, the widget is gone.

Comment: @JoséFonte Yes that's right this question is related to the other one. And yes I use GtkBulder. I know how to hide it with gtk_widget_hide_on_delete, but it will keep the widget in the memory. Is it possible not to keep the widget in the memory, but to call a brand new instance of it again when I need it?

Comment: Following the answers, it seems impossible!

Comment: @liberforce I see that with GtkBuilder all the widgets are created at parse and those are kept in memory from the beginning, so no need to bother about it, is that right?

Comment: Yes, GtkBuilder keeps the widgets around for later use. If you destroy them, they're gone. Please read the description of [GtkBuilder](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html#GtkBuilder.description)

Comment: If you really want to destroy and reload, if memory is more important than CPU for your use case, you may just create a separate .ui file with just your dialog, and handle it with a separate `GtkBuilder`, creating it each time you have to run the dialog. But I don't think it's worth the trouble...